# CRUD Edit can't edit the primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a table called `SectionUser` like this:

- `USER_ID` (`varchar(255)`)   (primary key)
- `NAME` (`varchar(255)`)

Here are sample values:

```
USER ID | NAME
--------+--------------    
EVTAB   | ELMER TABER
FAYKVIL | FAYK VILLET
```

Whenever I click the edit tab in row in table of my web page, I can retrieve the data. When I try to edit the "NAME". I can successfully edit the name. But I can't edit the `USER_ID` (which is my primary key)

When I try in debug mode, it won't get the `USER_ID` data when I edit data in textbox under `USER_ID`. But it gets the data from textbox in `NAME`.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult EditUser(string USER_ID)
    {
        if (USER_ID == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        SectionUser section = db.SectionUsers.Find(USER_ID);

        if (section == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(section);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(Users User)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Entry(User).State = EntityState.Modified;
                _context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Users");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.ToString();
        }

        return View(User);
    }
```

View (cshtml)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditUser", "Admin", FormMethod.Post,
                                  new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Section</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.USER_ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USER_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USER_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USER_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NAME, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NAME, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

The reason I edit my primary key is that it is the database model that is given to me. `SectionUser` has a foreign key to `UserRole`. So I used cascade updates. Whenever I edit the `USER_ID` of `SectionUser`, the `UserRole` `USER_ID` will also be updated.

Comment: Why would you want to edit a primary key value of a record ?

Comment: if u edit ur primary key, how will you system know which record it will be edit? ur primary key is the main reference for the record

Comment: I added my reason

Comment: Would you consider deleting the old record and **inserting** a new one?

Comment: @ElmoTabuzo *don't* edit the primary key. Just don't. Don't use a field with business significance as the primary key either. That's a serious design error. BTW no real system can have such a short User ID - are you working with the Northwind demo database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I tried:

I created a stored procedure that updates the primary key.

```
UPDATE dbo.SectionUser
SET USER_ID = @USER_ID
WHERE NAME = @NAME
```

Then I created a function `void execEditUserId()` that I invoke through my `EditUser()` Action method.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should refactor your db model to have a separate primary key column apart from other columns. Entity framework or other ORMs updates the data based on primary key, if you update your primary key value itself in the code, there is no way for entity framework to figure out which row to update.

Another way could be to use classic ado.net and write your own sql query.

The code answered by @Camilo would give you a runtime error :

> {"The property 'user_id' is part of the object's key information and
>   cannot be modified. "}

Comment: This will be a problem because this is a very large database

Comment: @ElmoTabuzo if this is a *real* database, it's a very large, very fundamental design problem that needs to be fixed. You can patch up the problems it causes but you'll *always* have problems. For example, what happens with related tables? Who's going to update *their* references?